# django map widget console showing DjangoGooglePointFieldWidget Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: python, django, google-maps, postgis

I'm trying to implement the django map widget
https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets

But there is no map appearing and i have this in the browser console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DjangoGooglePointFieldWidget is not defined
```

in settings.py, i have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'mapwidgets',
]

MAP_WIDGETS = {
    "GoogleStaticMapWidget": (
        ("zoom", 15),
        ("size", "320x320"),
    ),
    "GoogleStaticMapMarkerSettings": (
        ("color", "green"),
    ),
    "GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY": "AIzaSyA1fXsJSKqZH_Bl9d9wueJMlpXd-6tEJy0"
}
```

in my model.py

```
class CompanySettingEdit(forms.ModelForm):
     display_companyname = forms.CharField(label='Display Company Name', max_length=50, required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ("display_companyname","location_point")

        widgets = {
            'location_point': GooglePointFieldWidget,
        }
```

UPDATE:
my static files configuration in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../projectapp/static"),
)

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../../../static_root')
```

after running python manage.py collectstatic, static files are copied to another directory static_root - https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5JyS.jpg. notice that mapwidgets directory is not in the original project static directory. im running on development, i notice bootstrap static files are using the the file in static directory and not static_root

Am I missing something ? to I need to load anything in the template ?

Comment: Make sure you have used JQuery, Django Map Widgets needs JQuery dependency to work in your regular views. In Django Admin case, you don’t need to provide the jQuery just because it’s already available on django.jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [was encountered before](https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets/issues/26). The possible solutions:

1. Make sure you run `python manage.py collectstatic` so that the third-party static files are copied to `STATIC_ROOT` (more in [their readme](https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets))
2. If you are running in develoment mode, you must add static files serving view for `urls` (Helper link [#1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) and [#2](https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets/blob/master/example/example/urls.py#L13))
3. Make sure your template also has `{{form.media}}` somewhere in `<head>` or at the end of your `<body>` tag in your base html. ([example](https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets/blob/master/example/templates/cities/form.html#L4))

Comment: thank you. i still cant get it working (still same error in console) (i did 1,2,3).  i updated my question to include my static configuration. after running python manage.py collectstatic, static files are copied to another directory static_root - https://imgur.com/a/TmhYr. notice that mapwidgets directory is not in the original project static directory. im running on development, i notice bootstrap static files are using the the file in static directory and not static_root

Answer (score 1):

Actually no one asked for the template.
Based on this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/media/ 
it was the form.media that did the trick. I didnt use my own form name for the .media call.

Here is my html template file that had the field to display the map.

```
{% extends 'employee/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block page %}
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading bg-blue">
        <h4 class="panel-title text-center text-white">
          Company Settings
        </h4>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-body">         
          {{ companysetting_form.media }} <--- this did the trick
          <h4>Company Login Name: <a href="{% url 'employee-companychangename' %}">{{ request.user.employee.company.companyname }}</a></h4> 
          <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}            
            {% bootstrap_form companysetting_form %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pink">Update</button>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```